# my button(onClick) did'nt work over clickable component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[this is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZiw.png)
i have a component(Product) that is clickable.
one of his children is a button too. but when i click it, the Product's function executes.
how can i excepts my button to seperatly execute?

```
                    <ProductForm>
                   {
                       this.state.list.map((obj)=>{
                           return <Product
                           onselect={()=>{
                               this.select(obj.id)
                            }}
                           ondlt={()=>{this.dlt(obj.id)}}
                           key={obj.id}
                           obj={obj}/>
                       })
                   }
                </ProductForm>
```

// his child button:

delet

Comment: sounds like you need to use event.stopPropagation(). Basically it prevents the event from bubbling up : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: `stopPropagation` will work, but it's a bandaid. The problem is having nested interactive elements which makes interactions pretty terrible for everyone. Not only is it hard to develop, but the poor users that have to use it are going to suffer.

Comment: However, going this route id argue that `preventDefault` is more correct. Since the default action of the card click is popping the card out. You can `preventDefault` on the delete click and `e.isDefaultPrevented` or similar on the card to determine if you should handle the default action. i.e. pop the card out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate them into different sections and put the child button on top with `position: absolute` here is a sandbox example I made to show that

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-wy6fl?from-embed)